# Smart UPS 2200 & Windows 2008 R2 with Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, ups, apcupsd

We are setting up a new Windows 2008 R2 server and I am trying to get it to listen to the attached UPS and shut itself down gracefully when there is an outage.  Unfortunately, the included PowerChute Business refuses to install because it noticed that hyper-v is installed.  After some searching, I found that the network version of powerchute does have a version that supports hyper-v.  Unfortunately, the UPS (Smart UPS 2200 VA 2U rack mount I think) does not have a network card so that's not working.

Another option I found was APCUPSD, the open source UPS monitor.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get it to find the UPS.  The difficulty is that I cannot confirm if/how it is plugged in to the server, as I have never actually seen the UPS or the server.  I am told that the cable plugs in to an ethernet jack on the UPS and a USB port on the server and that it acts like a serial cable.  However: when I use the simple USB configuration for apcupsd it reports that it cannot find a USB device, but I can't figure out what device to use.  I *suspect* I need to use the smartups config, but I'm not sure what device name to use.  Being a Windows server, "ls /dev/" is unlikely to be very helpful.

Has anyone delt with a situation like this?  What am I doing wrong?  All I want to do is shut down the Hyper-V VMs and then the server (I have a PowerShell script that will do just that) when the power goes out.  Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I found out the hard way that you have to attach the right *kind* of serial cable.  I think the USB serial cable isn't supported in Windows.  Attaching a standard serial cable powered off the UPS (ouch).  It wouldn't work with a serial cable for a dumb UPS.  In the end I needed a 940-0024D.  The relevant portion of my apcupsd.conf looks like this:

UPSCABLE smart
UPSTYPE smartups
DEVICE COM1
LOCKFILE /var/lock
UPSCLASS standalone
UPSMODE disable

Very similar to the sample.